# Open a fragment from a cardView

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-cardview

How can i open a fragment from onClick in CardView?
i have a list in Cardview and when i clicked want to show in another fragment.
This is the adapter.class

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public TextView fecha_celula;
        public TextView nombre_celula;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            fecha_celula = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fecha_celula);
            nombre_celula = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre_celula);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Fragment nameAdd = new name_add();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, predicaAdd).commit();
        }
    }
```

and this is the layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:duplicateParentState="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar_celula"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_celula"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/fecha_celula"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/avatar_celula" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/nombre_celula"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fecha_celula"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/avatar_celula" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

I resolve the problem whith the onClick, now my problem is that i can't open another fragment. 
how i can call my method in myActivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OnClickListener` is not actually used anywhere, you have to connect it to a view, e.g. your `itemView` in the constructor.

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
```

In the `onClick()` method you can then use `getPosition()` to get the index of the clicked element.

Comment: Sorry to bump this, but there is no getPosition() method. Is there any new information that you could pass along to me regarding this?

Comment: RecyclerView.ViewHolder does have getPosition(). Although it seems like it has been deprecated, it should still be available:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html#getPosition()